# SwiftUI: Detecting delete key press in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, user-input, textfield

I am trying to create a text field, that can react to the user pressing the delete button on the numpad keyboard in iOS.

`.onKeyPress(_ key:action:)` works, but only for hardware keyboards and macOS (as far as I know).

Using `.onChange(of:)` and checking the value in the TextField works, but not the way I want. I want to react when *there are no characters in the TextField and the user is pressing delete* (cannot be done with `.onChange(of:)` as far as I know).

How would you go about implementing this?

Comment: You want to react to delete key press *only* when text is empty or *also*?

Answer (score -1):

This is the best code that I came up with and it works very well however the text is very small and it uses UIKit. I you’re not a fan of it. You’ll have to stick with the text comparison logic.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var text = ""

var body: some View {
    MyTextView(text: $text)
        .padding()
}
}

struct MyTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var text: String

class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var parent: MyTextView
    
    init(parent: MyTextView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        parent.text = textView.text
    }
    
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text.isEmpty && textView.text.isEmpty {
            print("Delete key pressed")
        }
        return true
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(parent: self)
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.delegate = context.coordinator
    return textView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = text
}
}
```

Update:
I also made the comparison logic:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var text = "Hello, World!"
@State private var old = "Hello, World!"

var body: some View {
    TextField("text" , text: $text)
        .onChange(of: text) {
            if text.count <= old.count {
                print("Deleted the letter: \(old.replacingOccurrences(of: text, with: ""))")
            }
            old = text
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Did the code work for you?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, the first solution works. However, I want it to be implemented in SwiftUI. The second solution, doesn't work according to what I need. The comparison cannot detect when the text field is empty and the user is hitting the delete button, which is what I want to do. Thanks anyway.